# Migrated posts treated as different user

Tags: bug, migration, user-accounts

I have multiple Stack Exchange accounts. Those include `StackOverflow.com` and `dba.StackExchange.com`. [I had asked a question a while back on Stack Overflow, which has since been migrated to dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58014/sql-server-difference-between-instance-name-and-instance-id).

On that post is a comment of mine which I had posted before the migration. However, after the migration, it's treated as if it's a different user. I would like to delete that comment, but I cannot delete it. I can on the other hand upvote that comment (which you're not supposed to be able to upvote your own comments). In fact, my name on that comment isn't even a hyperlink (cannot hover / click on it as usual). The same applies to my comments on answers on that post.

I would expect to have the same control over the post and comments on that post as before, given it is my post/comment. Right?

Answer (score 3):

The comment has been deleted.

The problem originates the fact that you have multiple accounts and they have not been merged. You can learn about merging accounts here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: I don't have two separate accounts, I have one single account (linked to my Gmail) which I use for all SE networks.

Comment: Well, the system thinks that the user that left that comment on SO originally was a different user than the one that owns the question, @Jerry perhaps because it was migrated here before your accounts were linked together (which is a manual action you have to take, even if the e-mail address matches). Linking the accounts will update ownership of first class citizens like questions and answers, but might not work for less important citizens like comments. I don't know why that is, sorry.